# Issue with pagination buttons, can't get another article

Tags: php, html, pagination

I have an issue with pagination, I try to make my problem clearly as possible

First, of all, I have filters, and a list of articles. I'm getting what list from file `fetch_data.php`

On this page, I'm doing some `SQL query corrections`, and make while circle to render date.

I want to make a pagination for it.

First off all what I do is in start of file set code like this.

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
```

Then my filter corrections in SQL quest `WHERE` statement, if need it I will upload it.

Then I write code for pagination

```
    $no_of_records_per_page = 1; // record for show (its works) 
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page; 
// In this line im cut my querty start SELECT * and replace it with SELECT count (*) with conditions who made by filters. 
    $str2 = substr($query, 12); 
    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT count(*)";
    
    $total_pages_sql .= $str2; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$total_pages_sql);
    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
```

And when just add in my main `query` LIMIT.

```
  $query .= "LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
```

And then at the end of the file, I put code

```
<div class="content">           
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It's important to say all this shows in `index.php`, but now the problem is this. My
[image]

Buttons working changing the pagination URL, but not working right. If I chose filter who has only one record, then the NEXT button make invisible so its working,

But why if I just use pagination NEXT Button I always get the same article

Any know why?

UPDATED Full php files in the link bellow

Index.php code is [here](http://www.rohero.lt/index.txt)

fetch_data.php code is [here](http://www.rohero.lt/feth.txt)

Comment: so what is the question? Is it that your next button is showing up despite the fact that your filter option should disable it or rather that is working?

Comment: then i press next button i dont get another article, it will be just same article

Comment: Just to make it clear: when you click `Next`, the page number changes correctly, but it's always the same article, or the page number doesn't change?

Comment: did you check string of your query? maybe offset is not correct

Comment: Is the query incorrect since there is no space between `SELECT count(*)` and `LIMIT ..."`? I see the concatenation but that does not automatically add a space.

Comment: its currect, if query was not right i dont get any article

Comment: @fth because have more query code in bellow check im add my full code files

Comment: When you echo the query is the offset being set correctly? Are the urls on the next and previous buttons showing the right page number?

Comment: Hi, you are getting `pageno` using `$_POST['pageno']` but this should be `$_GET['pageno']` because here `pageno` will be in href . So that's why its going in else part always i.e: `$pageno = 1;`.

Comment: thenk you, but problem is im getting the same article just href  changing by pages

Comment: did you change to `$_GET`  i.e : `if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];} else{ ..`  ?

Comment: yes, i change what

Comment: also your whole code is inside `if(isset($_POST["action"]))` so when you click on pages this it will not go inside your code and you don't have any code related to `$_GET` in your index.php so nothing will change . I hope you are getting what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a example of Ajax Pagination with PHP and MySQLi.

(1). First Create Database Table name `developers` :

```
CREATE TABLE `developers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `skills` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

(2).Insert data in `developers` Table:

```
INSERT INTO `developers` (`id`, `name`, `skills`, `address`, `gender`, `designation`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'Smith', 'Java', 'Newyork', 'Male', 'Software Engineer', 34),
(2, 'David', 'PHP', 'London', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 28),
(3, 'Rhodes', 'jQuery', 'New Jersy', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 30),
(4, 'Sara', 'JavaScript', 'Delhi', 'Female', 'Web Developer', 25),
(5, 'Shyrlin', 'NodeJS', 'Tokiyo', 'Female', 'Programmer', 35),
(6, 'Steve', 'Angular', 'London', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 28),
(7, 'Cook', 'MySQL', 'Paris', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 26),
(8, 'Root', 'HTML', 'Paris', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 28),
(9, 'William', 'jQuery', 'Sydney', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 23),
(10, 'Nathan', 'PHP', 'London', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 28),
(11, 'Shri', 'PHP', 'Delhi', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 38),
(12, 'Jay', 'PHP', 'Delhi, India', 'Male', 'Web Developer', 30);
```

**(3) Create index.php**

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
$perPage = 5;
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM developers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$totalPages = ceil($totalRecords/$perPage)
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/simple-bootstrap-paginator.js"></script>
<script src="js/pagination.js"></script>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Skills</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="content">     
            </tbody>
        </table>   
        <div id="pagination"></div>    
        <input type="hidden" id="totalPages" value="<?php echo $totalPages; ?>">    
    </div>    
</div>
```

**(5) Create pagination.js**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var totalPage = parseInt($('#totalPages').val());   
        var pag = $('#pagination').simplePaginator({
            totalPages: totalPage,
            maxButtonsVisible: 5,
            currentPage: 1,
            nextLabel: 'Next',
            prevLabel: 'Prev',
            firstLabel: 'First',
            lastLabel: 'Last',
            clickCurrentPage: true,
            pageChange: function(page) {            
                $("#content").html('<tr><td colspan="6"><strong>loading...</strong></td></tr>');
                $.ajax({
                    url:"load_data.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType: "json",       
                    data:{page: page},
                    success:function(responseData){
                        $('#content').html(responseData.html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**(6) Create load_data.php**

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
$perPage = 5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
    // type-casting to integer to avoid SQL injection
    $page  = (int)$_GET["page"]; 
} else { 
    $page=1; 
};  
$startFrom = ($page-1) * $perPage;  
$sqlQuery = "SELECT id, name, age, address, skills, designation
    FROM developers ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $startFrom, $perPage";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery); 
$paginationHtml = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
    $paginationHtml.='<tr>';  
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["age"].'</td>'; 
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["address"].'</td>';
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["skills"].'</td>';
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>'; 
    $paginationHtml.='</tr>';  
} 
$jsonData = array(
    "html"  => $paginationHtml, 
);
echo json_encode($jsonData); 
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example, but my system different, i dont have table and my code not in the same php file, so please check my updated post with full code in the files.

Comment: `but my system different` & `i dont have table` & `my code not in the same php file` means??

Comment: look my updated code. like you see, in the fetch_data.php exist output for artical, but in the index.php it shows.

Comment: In your example you do it with table.

Comment: so what you want??

Comment: i want make pagination buttons work in my case

Comment: I've edited code to be `$page  = (int)$_GET["page"];` in order to avoid SQL injection. I'd like to encourage everybody to use safe code examples with a short explanation why it's important. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The answer @KUMAR provided is a really good one, which would get all of your issues fixed. Also, you should follow his code in order to get a grasp about how clean your code should be for debugging, readability purposes.

You have many issues with your code, from best practices perspective, that in my opinion need your attention before trying to debug the application.

I find your code pretty hard to follow, for example:

You are using a lot of hardcoded strings for doing checks in order to construct your query.

Here: `WHERE ad.status='Patvirtintas'`, from a quick search on Google Translate, I found out that it means Approved. Why store it as a string in the database, when you can use a flag for it. 0/1 for Not Approved/Approved. Or different numbers, if there are multiple statuses.

Also, for cleaning your code, this codes would be really good to be stored inside a so called ENUM, which in PHP you can write as a class, for example:

```html
class PostStatus
{
    const NotApproved = 0;
    const Approved = 1;
}

$postStatus = PostStatus::Approved;
```

And the list goes on, from spacing, indentation. I suggest you should take a course for clean code.

You should separate your code, use one file, where you construct the query, fetch the data from the database, create a JSON array with it, and return as a response, without appending any HTML, CSS, JavaScript to the returned response.

Use ajax calls to the file I mentioned above, with parameters for the desired page, and I am more than sure that it should work fine.

Also, for PHP instead of:

`<a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>`

use the shorthand and the ternary operator (in case your version of PHP is above 5, if I am not mistaking) and it will look something like this in your case:

`<a href="<?= $pageno >= $total_pages ? '#' : '?pageno=". ($pageno + 1) . "' ?>">Next</a>`

Trust me, use the code given by KUMAR above, and adapt it to your needs. No one will give you something that works out of the box, because no one can test it, or has enough knowledge about your application and what is the desired behavior.